# Convergence of the sequence $a_n=\sum_{k=n}^{2n} {1\over {k^2}}$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, proof-verification, convergence-divergence

A sequence is given $\{a_n\}$ where $$a_n=\sum_{k=n}^{2n} {1\over {k^2}}$$ Can I write $$a_n=\sum_{k=n}^{2n} {1\over {k^2}}\\=\sum_{k=1}^{2n} {1\over {k^2}}-\sum_{k=1}^{n-1} {1\over {k^2}}$$.

Then $$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}a_n=\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\sum_{k=1}^{2n} {1\over {k^2}}-\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\sum_{k=1}^{n-1} {1\over {k^2}}\\=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{1\over {n^2}}-\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{1\over {n^2}}\\=0.$$

Is it correct $?$ I've a doubt because although I think when we take the limit to $\infty$ both $n$ and $2n$ will go  all the same but should not there be some little differences as well $?$

Comment: It is Cauchy criterion applied to a convergent series.

Comment: Yes. More generally, if $b_1,\dots,$ is a convergent sequence then $b_{2n}-b_n\to 0$. In this case, $b_n=\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{1}{k^2}$.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews: OK. So what I have been thinking was correct then?

Comment: Have you proven that $\lim_{N\to\infty}\sum_{n=1}^{N}\frac{1}{n^2}$ exists?  If so, then your approach is fine.

Comment: @Dr.MV: I have not proven myself though but I have read the proof from book.S.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your approach is fine if we already know that $\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{1}{k^2}$ exists.

But there is a more straightforward way to show that $\lim_{n\to \infty}\sum_{k=n}^{2n}\frac{1}{k^2}=0$.  Simply note that

$$\sum_{k=n}^{2n}\frac{1}{k^2}\le \sum_{k=n}^{2n}\frac{1}{n^2}=\frac{n+1}{n^2}$$

which approaches $0$ as $n\to \infty$.

---

A simple way to show that $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^2}$ exists is to note that

$$\begin{align}
\sum_{n=1}^N \frac{1}{n^2}&\le 1+\sum_{n=2}^N \frac{1}{n(n-1)}\\\\
&=1+\sum_{n=2}^N \left(\frac{1}{n-1}-\frac{1}{n}\right)\\\\
&=2-\frac{1}{N}\\\\
&\to 2\,\,\text{as}\,\,N\to \infty
\end{align}$$

Answer (score 0):

$a_{n+1}-a_n= 1/{(2n+1)}^2 +1/{(2n+2)}^2 - 1/n^2$. Since the infinite sum of each term is convergent, the infinite sum of the RHS is convergent and thus $\sum_n a_{n+1}-a_n$ is convergent. But this is just $a_n$.

Comment: The sum is not $a_n$, nor is it the limit of $a_n$, but rather it's a limit of $a_n-a_1$. You can still conclude that $a_n$ has a limit though. BTW, I really think you should start using LaTeX to make your answers more readable.